# How to store values from a loop and return a compact values in laravel 8. i got only one values when i return

Tags: php, model-view-controller, laravel-8

this is the code in controller i want to get a compact values but it is returning only one values

```
public function index()
    {
       
        $take_data = Product::whereNotNull('expiry_date')->select('expiry_date','name')->get(); 
        $count = count($take_data);
        $take_today_date = date('Y-m-d');
      
      for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++)
    
       {
        
         $expiry_date = strtotime($take_data[$i]->expiry_date);
         $today_date = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
        
 
        if($expiry_date < $today_date)
     {
        $result = abs($today_date - $expiry_date); 
        $years = floor( $result / (365*60*60*24));
        $months = floor(( $result - $years * 365*60*60*24) /(30*60*60*24));
        $days = $take_data[$i]->name." : Expired ". floor(( $result - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24))." days ago. ";   
          
       return $days;
     }
    }        
  }
```

While putting echo instead of return i got all values but when i put return i got only one values

Comment: Well you want to take `return` out of the loop.  Also, you probably want an array so `$days[] = ....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must create an array $days before the for loop and add values on it in the loop.
like this

```
    public function index()
    {  
        $take_data = Product::whereNotNull('expiry_date')->select('expiry_date','name')->get(); 
        $count = count($take_data);
        $take_today_date = date('Y-m-d');
        $days = [];

        for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            $expiry_date = strtotime($take_data[$i]->expiry_date);
            $today_date = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
 
            if($expiry_date < $today_date) {
                $result = abs($today_date - $expiry_date); 
                $years = floor( $result / (365*60*60*24));
                $months = floor(( $result - $years * 365*60*60*24) /(30*60*60*24));
                $days[] = $take_data[$i]->name." : Expired ". floor(( $result - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24))." days ago. ";   
            }
        }

        return $days;
    }
```

Because when there is a return, it directly returns the first value it finds, while the echo will just output.
However the return must be at the end, after the loop.